# How are people unit testing code that uses Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, unit-testing, linq-to-sql

How are people unit testing code that uses Linq to SQL?

Comment: I'm just trying out ASP.NET MVC with Linq2Sql and tried to write a few unit tests for the "TaskList" demo application. Ran into very strange errors, and then I stumble across this. Very sad to see something so simple thwart a great technology stack.

Comment: Look at this answer to see how to effectively and successfully test with LINQ to SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128640/how-to-remove-unit-of-work-functionality-from-repositories-using-ioc/4132186#4132186

Comment: There are enough query-parts that work fine with linq to objects that don't with linq to sql. It would be great if we had a mechanism to test linq2sql compatibility without actually running against an SQL Server.(for SQL Server that is, implementations for other DBMS may support other expression transformation). When you want to test your Specification Pattern or a DSL to assemble query parts (filters, transformations, aggregations) there seems to be no alternative to running the tests against an actual db instance. Or is there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update:

Fredrik has put an example solution on how to do unit test linq2sql applications over at his blog. You can download it at:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120415022448/http://iridescence.no/post/DataContext-Repository-Pattern-Example-Code.aspx

Not only do I think its great that he posted an example solution, he also managed to extract interfaces for all classes, which makes the design more decoupled.

My old post:

*I found these blogs that I think are a good start for making the DataContext wrapper:
[Link1](http://web.archive.org/web/20120414060200/http://iridescence.no/post/Linq-to-Sql-Programming-Against-an-Interface-and-the-Repository-Pattern.aspx)
[Link2](http://nixusg.com/post/2008/08/05/The-Automated-Testing-Continuum-Part-2-(Unit-Testing-LinQ).aspx)

They cover almost the same topic except that the first one implements means for extracting interfaces for the tables as well. The second one is more extensive though, so I included it as well.*

Comment: The actual address on the first link is incorrect, copy and paste the address to see the really useful article.

Comment: I was able to find the example code (zip download works too) and Link1 on the Way Back Machine so those links are fixed now. I wasn't able to find a working copy of Link2.

Answer (score 5):

3 years late, but this is how I do it:

https://github.com/lukesampson/LinqToSQL-test-extensions/

No need to write a wrapper or do lots of plumbing, just drop the T4 template next to your .dbml and you get:

1. An interface for your data context e.g. IExampleDataContext
2. An in-memory mock for your data context e.g. MemoryExampleDataContext

Both will automatically use the mappings you've already configured in your DBML.

So you can do things like

```
public class ProductRepo {
    IExampleDataContext DB { get; set };
    public ProductRepo(IExampleDataContext db) {
        DB = db;
    }

    public List<Product> GetProducts() {
        return DB.Products.ToList();
    }
}
```

and you can call that with either

```
new ProductRepo(new MemoryExampleDataContext()).GetProducts(); // for testing
```

or

```
new ProductRepo(new ExampleDataContext()).GetProducts(); // use the real DB
```

Comment: It's a great solution, worked like a charm, THANK you ! It only lacks stored procedures in Interface.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the DataContext, then mock the wrapper.  It's the fastest way to get it done, although it requires coding for testing, which some people think smells.  But sometimes, when you have dependencies that cannot be (easily) mocked, it's the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you don't need to test the part of the code that uses LINQ to SQL but if you really want to, you can use the same data sets that you're querying against the server and turn them into in-memory objects and run the LINQ queries against that (which would use the Enumerable methods instead of Queryable).

Another option is to use Matt Warren's [mockable version of the DataContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/archive/2008/05/04/mocks-nix-an-extensible-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx).

You can also get the SQL statements that LINQ to SQL uses by getting them via the debugger (from the IQueryable object), check those manually, and then include them in the automated tests.

Comment: Why may someone not need to test the part of the code that uses LINQ to SQL? I'm e.g. writing an asp.net mvc web page where many controllers use LINQ to SQL and I have to test these controllers...

Comment: I meant that you don't need to make sure that LINQ to SQL itself works as advertised (since Microsoft already tested that for you) as opposed to your code that uses any results from the LINQ to SQL classes.

Answer (score 2):

Linq makes testing much easier. Linq queries work just as well on Lists as on the Linq-to-sql stuff. You can swap out Linq to SQL for list objects and test that way.

Comment: The problem is stuff like Foreign Key relationships (EntitySet/EntityRef) and Colums where `IsDbGenerated = true`.

Comment: You really have to be careful with this approach. Linq to SQL and Linq to Objects are different providers and there's no guarantee they'll operate exactly the same (and in practice, they sometimes will not). Especially in this case, where Linq to SQL is a subset of Linq to Objects. I predict many green unit tests, followed by runtime failures.

Answer (score 2):

Mattwar over at [The Wayward Web Log](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/archive/2008/05/04/mocks-nix-an-extensible-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx) had a great article about how to mock up an extensible Linq2Sql data context. Check it out -- [MOCKS NIX - AN EXTENSIBLE LINQ TO SQL DATACONTEXT](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/archive/2008/05/04/mocks-nix-an-extensible-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL is actually really nice to unit test as it has the ability to create databases on the fly from what is defined in your DBML.

It makes it really nice to test a ORM layer by creating the DB through the DataContext and having it empty to begin with.

I cover it on my blog here: http://web.archive.org/web/20090526231317/http://www.aaron-powell.com/blog/may-2008/unit-testing-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: I took a look at the author's current website and couldn't find the post that is mentioned. I have edited the answer with the best match that I could find from the Way Back Machine since the previous link was broken.

Comment: Yep it would appear that that post is lost in the sands of time (and multiple migrations). But really the solution I proposed there **isn't** unit testing, it's integration testing